# Quickbooks Webconnector giving QBXML parsing error in quickbooks desktop api xml

Tags: xml, parsing, desktop, quickbooks, qbxml

I am getting QBXML validator parsing error for the QBXML below

```
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
      <CustomerQueryRq>
         <FullName>Perich Advertising</FullName>
         <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
      </CustomerQueryRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

```
Requested validation for QB Web Connector (qwc), file has processing instruction indicating <?qbxml... obeying processing instruction
Error during validation: D, Conversion from string "Line: 3
LinePos: 8
Src Text: <" to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

QBXML validator does not have any parsing error for Quickbooks(US), it is giving error for Webconnector only. I don't know what is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're validating against the wrong schema.

You should *not* be validating against the `QuickBooks Web Connector` schema. You should be validating against the *`QuickBooks`* schema. (You would only validate against the `QuickBooks Web Connector` schema if you were creating a *configuration file* for the Web Connector, not an actual request you're sending *through the Web Connector, to QuickBooks*.)

Validation against the QuickBooks schema instead.

With that said, are you *100% sure* that what you posted is actually what got sent to QuickBooks? Is this from the Web Connector log in VERBOSE mode?